# Local variables vs method access

Tags: c#, performance

I had a argument with a co worker about the performance of a statement. It was roughly something like below.

```
var a = class.member.member1.variable;
```

Is it faster to create a local variable for the variable and use it through out the process which the variable is needed, or access the variable via `.`. I believe it is better to create local variable but I wasn't exactly sure performance wise. I remember reading somewhere it is faster then accessing `.`.

Comment: don't ask, measure it!

Comment: It also depends on the property you are accessing.  For example, a property could have some calculation being performed in it's get accessor.

Comment: Try to measure it yourself by writing short program that uses a loop to execute the two different approaches a thousand times (or some large number).  Then find calculate the average time for each. Use the [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class to accurately measure the time.  Then tell us your results. We'll be interested to learn what you find out :)

Comment: I have tried it and the results come back very small different, we are talking in milliseconds. I did this over a couple hundred. I couldn't remember there reason why I started the habit of using local variable when I start accessing methods that were many layers deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `.` (access operator), it means that the runtime environment first needs to find out where the object is located, next calculate at which position the field is located, and then fetch that value.

If you access a property, it is even worse, because the runtime environment sometimes needs to make a call (as @RowlandShaw states: sometimes access to a property can be inlined, in that case it doesn't make any difference whether you access the field directly or use a property). And a property does not always provides the value instantly: there can be calculations in between.

A local variable on the other hand, is can be accessed *directly*, in many cases it will be put in a register as well to boost performance further (which is roughly a factor of 5-10). So indeed a local variable will nearly always be faster.

In case the field you aim to address is read only, a smart compiler can optimize the call, because it knows for sure, that the value wont change. But in many cases (for instance if you access a property) you cannot know whether the value has changed between two calls because another thread can have modified the object concurrently.

There is not much difference between `var` being a *reference type* or a *value type*. In the case of a reference type, the references will be shortcutted, in the case of a value type (primitives and structs), the value will be copied.

The only possible downside performancewise using a local variable, if the `var` is a large struct. In that case, copying the values can result in signifant overhead.

**Short answer**: If you know the *value* of the thing you access won't change (or you don't care much about it), you better store it in a local variable for performance reasons. Otherwise, you should keep using a access to the field/property. In a very rare case it can result in overhead: if it is a value type and the size of the type is extremely large: in that case the `struct` must be copied an can result in a large amount of instructions.

Comment: Assuming the compiler can't/hasn't inlined the calls

Comment: @RowlandShaw: That's why it states "sometimes". Indeed you're right that a straightforward getter will in many cases be optimized using inline calls. But anyway by using a local variable, you tell the compiler the value won't change. Compilers can reason (liveness analysis, etc.) over local variables than over a heap.